# Need help identifying SOD-123 diode marked S3L

Tags: diodes, identification

I'm having trouble identifying a SOD-123 diode marked 'S3L'.

I've found references to 'S3' in three data sheets:

- https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds11012.pdf
- https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/2/882/SSM5818SLGP-pdf.php
- https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1002951/LGE/SD101AW/1

[image]

It's the 'L' that's throwing me!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a [MBR130 / NRVB130](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mbr130t1-d.pdf) diode from Onsemi (dot below the marking).

Picture of a component in [RS Components](https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/diodes-schottky-et-de-redressements/6880492):
[image]

Comment: Note that the X in the picture, and the L in the question, are noted on the datasheet as being the date code, so this character will differ based on when the part is made.